# FluentValidation - returns default response when object is NULL

Tags: c#, .net, validation, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I hope you are well. I have a question to ask you. There is an architecture I use for a project. I'm using fluentvalidation on the server side. I have no problems with all the validations I use, but the notnull() validation does not give me the output I want. In short, when I get a validation error, the architecture I use catches the error with the middleware and allows me to return it the way I want. But when I use notnull, my middleware and verification codes do not activate. hence returning the default. Is this a mistake? here are the codes I used:

**ValidationAspect.cs:**

```
public class ValidationAspect : MethodInterception
{
    private Type _validatorType;
    public ValidationAspect(Type validatorType)
    {
        if (!typeof(IValidator).IsAssignableFrom(validatorType))
        {
            throw new System.Exception("Bu bir doğrulama sınıfı değil");
        }

        _validatorType = validatorType;
    }
    protected override void OnBefore(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var validator = (IValidator)Activator.CreateInstance(_validatorType);
        var entityType = _validatorType.BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        var entities = invocation.Arguments.Where(t => t.GetType() == entityType);
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            ValidationTool.Validate(validator, entity);
        }
    }
}
```

**ValidationTool.cs:**

```
 public class ValidationTool
 {
     public static void Validate(IValidator validator, object entity)
     {
         var context = new ValidationContext<Object>(entity);
         var result = validator.Validate(context);

         if (!result.IsValid)
         {
             throw new ValidationException(result.Errors);
         }
     }
 }
```

**ExceptionMiddleware.cs**

```
private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext httpContext, Exception e)
{
    httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

    IEnumerable<ValidationFailure> errors;

    if (e.GetType() == typeof(ValidationException))
    {
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

        errors = ((ValidationException)e).Errors;

        var errorPropertyDetail = new List<ErrorPropertyDetails>();

        foreach (var error in errors)
        {
            var err = new ErrorPropertyDetails
            {
                PropertyName = error.PropertyName,
                ErrorMessage = error.ErrorMessage,
            };
            errorPropertyDetail.Add(err);
        }

        return httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(new ValidationErrorDetail
        {
            Status = false,
            Message = "Validation Error",
            Errors = errorPropertyDetail
        }.ToString());
    }

    if (e.GetType() == typeof(SecurityException))
    {
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;

        return httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(new ErrorDetails
        {
            Status = false,
            Message = "Authentication Error",
        }.ToString());
    }

    return httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(new ErrorDetails
    {
        Status = false,
        Message = "Internal Server Error"
    }.ToString());
}
```

**When the request cannot pass validation, it comes here as ValidationException. But if an object comes as null, it doesn't come here.**

**RegisterValidator.cs**

```
    public class RegisterValidator : AbstractValidator<UserRegisterDto>
    {
        public RegisterValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(r => r.FirstName).NotEmpty().NotNull();
            RuleFor(r => r.LastName).NotEmpty().NotNull();
            RuleFor(r => r.Email).NotEmpty().NotNull();
            RuleFor(r => r.Password).NotEmpty().NotNull().Must(r => r.Length > 8).WithMessage("Şifre alanı en az 8 karakter olmalıdır");
            RuleFor(r => r.Status).NotEmpty().NotNull();
        }
    }
```

> I'm adding a few images to explain it better to you.

[image: Normally the response should be like this]

[image: response when sent null]

Can you help me to fix this error (I don't know if it is an error)?

Comment: Seems like you are applying the `[Required]` attribute to the `FirstName` property in your model class. It does not passed the validation as there is default model state handling. You need to disable it. [Async Action Filter not working. ASP.NET Core Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73011490/async-action-filter-not-working-asp-net-core-web-api). Otherwise, you should remove applying Validation Attribute from the properties.

Comment: Man this really worked. Thank you for the answer